# Table cell issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Table .cells will return all the inner cells in table. It is working fine in IE.But in Chrome .cells will return 'undefined' because no such property exists.We have to loop through each row to find the cells.Is there any other way to get all the cells in chrome?

```
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTable").cells.length;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " cells in 
     the first tr element.";
}

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing called `document.getElementById("myTable").cells.length` 
the `.cells` actually returns nothing, thus your `x` variable returns undefined and you don't get the cell numbers.

Instead, you can do the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
     var x = document.getElementById("myTable");
     // if you need all the cells which is td elements
     var cells = x.getElementsByTagName('td');
     
     // if you need only cells in a single row which is a tr element
     var cellsPerRow = x.getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + cellsPerRow.length + " cells in the first tr element." + "And " + cells.length + " cells in total" ;
}

myFunction();
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
      <td>cell 1</td>
      <td>cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>cell 3</td>
      <td>cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id='demo'></div>
```